# Need clarification of "conforming subsets" in “A Simple Proof of Zorn's Lemma” by J. Lewin

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

I am having difficulties with the definition of a "conforming subset" in J. Lewin's [A Simple Proof of Zorn's Lemma](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs):

The definition includes the statement: "For every element of $x\in A$, we have $x=f(P(A,x))$" where $f$ is a choice function that "assigns to every chain in $X$, a strict upper bound" and $P(A,x) = \{y\in A ~|~ y \lt x\}$.

**My Question:** Why is the choice function necessary here? Isn't $x$, by definition, a strict upper bound of the initial segment (and chain) $P(A,x)$?

Comment: The point is that $f$ selects, “simultaneously”, to every chain in $X$ a strict upper bound. The important point is not that $x$ is a strict upper bound, but that you have a way of selecting an upper bound for every chain, and that for chains of the form $P(A,x)$ the choice is given by $x$. Note that $x$ need not be the *only* strict upper bound to the chain $P(A,x)$. For $P(A,x)\cup\{x\}$ is also a chain, and if that has a strict upper bound, then it is also a strict upper bound for $P(A,x)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you give simple example of a conforming and a non-conforming subset in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conforming subsets are unique for each order type, and their exact elements depends on the choice of the choice function.

The point of this definition is to hide the transfinite recursion, but it is exactly that. A transfinite recursion. It means that we start with $\varnothing$, which is a chain, and use the choice function to select an upper bound of this chain. Then we have some $\{x\}$, where $x$ was the upper bound chosen for $\varnothing$; so it is either that $x$ is maximal, or the chain has a strict upper bound, say $y$, so we have the chain $\{x,y\}$, etc.

Now you can still ask, why do we need the choice function? In general there is no unique choice of upper bounds. And we will generally need to make infinitely many of these choices.

When looking at this from the recursion point of view, the choice function is needed for the recursion process to be well-defined to begin with. Which is necessary for the conforming subset definition to be useful (i.e., to produce a chain, rather than just a subset).

Comment: Can you give a simple example of a subset $A$ of $X$ that satisfies the first requirement for being conforming, but not the second (as defined in the proof)? I don't see how it is possible.

Comment: Suppose that $x,y$ are both *minimal* elements, then $P(A,x)=P(A,y)=\varnothing$. But at most one of $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are conforming.

Comment: In general your intuition is coming from a linear order when you hear "chains", but here you should think "tree" instead. So that $P(A,x)$ can be any other successor of $x$'s predecessor, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have constructed this "tree" function mapping each chain in X to the set of all of its strict upper bounds in X, but I am having trouble applying AC. I have a family of sets, but I am having trouble proving each member is non-empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By assumption, every chain has an upper bound. So if a chain does not have *strict* upper bounds, its upper bound is a maximal element.